# validating a phone number

Tags: javascript

How can I determine if an input is a valid home phone number (without area code)?

Comment: Are you trying to ask about if/else syntax generally (e.g., `else` should *not* have `()` after it), or how to write the specific if condition required for phone number validation? *"valid home phone number*" - Valid in what country?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the best option for validating a phone number.

you can use it on the html input tag like this (this may not be supported in all browsers):

```
<input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{4}$" required >
```

or you can test a regex string in you code like this (also, this is the correct format for you function above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //function\\
     function validPhone(phoneNum) {
         var reg = new RegExp("^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
         if (reg.test(phoneNum)) {
             return "True";
         }
         else {
             return "False";
         }
     }
</script>
```

and if you want to make it short and sweet and you just need to return a bool value, you can do do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //function\\
     function validPhone(phoneNum) {
         var reg = new RegExp("^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
         return reg.test(phoneNum);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good.  Though I'd put a question mark after the hyphen to allow it to be optional. Also your regex is in quotes so you need double backslash for \\d

Answer (score 0):

You should only have parenthesis/brackets after an else if statement. Not an else statement.

Example:
    If(true){
    }else if(true){
    }

Or

```
If(true){
}else{
}
```

NOT
    if(true){
    }else(){
    }